# Run aws lambda upload file (python) with test event

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I want to create lambda function which upload csv file to s3 bucket. To performance test, I'm trying to configure test event (using s3_put defaul template only put my bucket name and new file name).

**test_event**

```
{
  "Records": [
    {
      "eventVersion": "2.0",
      "eventSource": "aws:s3",
      "awsRegion": "eu-central-1",
      "eventTime": "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
      "eventName": "ObjectCreated:Put",
      "userIdentity": {
        "principalId": "EXAMPLE"
      },
      "requestParameters": {
        "sourceIPAddress": "127.0.0.1"
      },
      "responseElements": {
        "x-amz-request-id": "EXAMPLE123456789",
        "x-amz-id-2": "EXAMPLE123/5678abcder455relambdaisawesome/mnopqrdtygfwxyzABCDEFGH"
      },
      "s3": {
        "s3SchemaVersion": "1.0",
        "configurationId": "testConfigRule",
        "bucket": {
          "name": "MY_BUCKET",
          "ownerIdentity": {
            "principalId": "EXAMPLE"
          },
          "arn": "arn:aws:s3:::MY_BUCKET"
        },
        "object": {
          "key": "MY_NEY_FILE_NAME",
          "size": 1024,
          "eTag": "01234567847647383cdef0123456789abcdef",
          "sequencer": "0A1B2Cghfdjd3D4E5F678901"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**lambda_function.py**

```
import os
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError
SECRET_KEY = "XXXX"
ACCESS_KEY = "XXXX"
processed_folder = "drivers"

    def lambda_handler(event, context):
        """Upload a file to an S3 bucket
        """
        for record in event['Records']:
            # Create some variables that make it easier to work with the data in the
            # event record.
            bucket = record['s3']['bucket']['name'
            key = record['s3']['object']['key']
            file_name = ????
        s3_client = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY, aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY)
        try:
            response = s3_client.upload_file(file_name, bucket, key)
        except ClientError as e:
            logging.error(e)
            return False
        return True
```

And for obvious reasons, I'm getting a mistake `"name 'file_name' is not defined"`
How do I add the file to configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filename in S3 is in the "Key" component.

For example a file in "images" folder of Bucket named "Resources" with filename "mountains.jpg" will have file key as "images/mountains.jpg"

So, in order to extract the filename you will have to split the filename and extract out of it.

---

By the way, the format of your test_event is that of an Event which is triggered when a file is added on S3. Is your lambda triggered when a file is added to S3..??

The s3 fileupload function takes the bucketname, key and the file content.
So ideally your filename should contain the content of the file you want to upload.

Comment: test_event is just default sample from drop-down list on the lambda function page. All I've changed is the name bucket and file_name. As I understand it, the Key value is the path to the saved file in s3. And I am interested in how I can specify the path to the file that I am going to download, for example, from the Internet.

Comment: In order to do that you can just pass the test-event as
{filename:"yourfilename"}. (Select the HelloWorld template in the dropdown).
And in your code you can access the filename by event["filename"]